# Nginx / PHP-FPM drop ajax requests intermittently, how could one pinpoint the cause?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have an issue I cannot get to grips with. We have an app server that has mysteriously started "dropping requests".  These are ajax requests.

I restart `php5-fpm`, all runs fine for a few minutes then the success rate degrades over the subsequent hours. When there is a certain load, the ajax connexion come back .. not truncated, but empty of their payload.

I am out of ideas on how to tackle this, I am not often faced with these type of issues.

- Server has 128M of ram
- 24 CPU's,

Here is Nginx.conf, buffer configuration and  fastcgi_temp_path was added, but nothing is written to the /tmp directory.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

         client_body_buffer_size     100m;
         client_max_body_size        100m;

        # proxy buffer settings
        proxy_buffer_size   1020k;
        proxy_buffers   256 4k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size   1020k;
        fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/nginx_fastcgi;
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

        ## SSL CONFIGURATION ##
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
        # L'ECDHE sera proposé au navigateur par l'ajout de HIGH dans la directive ssl_ciphers
        ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4:!DH";

        # La directive ssl_prefer_server_ciphers permet de forcer le navigateur à utiliser les préférences de chiffrement du serveur
        # Sans cette directive, le Perfect Forward Secrecy risque de ne pas être activé car l'ECDHE ne sera pas proposé en premier
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ## END SSL CONFIGURATOIN ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    # Enable gzip compression.
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # Compression level (1-9).
    # 5 is a perfect compromise between size and CPU usage, offering about
    # 75% reduction for most ASCII files (almost identical to level 9).
    gzip_comp_level 5;

    # Don't compress anything that's already small and unlikely to shrink much
    # if at all (the default is 20 bytes, which is bad as that usually leads to
    # larger files after gzipping).
    gzip_min_length 256;

    # Compress data even for clients that are connecting to us via proxies,
    # identified by the "Via" header (required for CloudFront).
    gzip_proxied any;

    # Tell proxies to cache both the gzipped and regular version of a resource
    # whenever the client's Accept-Encoding capabilities header varies;
    # Avoids the issue where a non-gzip capable client (which is extremely rare
    # today) would display gibberish if their proxy gave them the gzipped version.
    gzip_vary on;

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types.
    gzip_types
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/atom+xml
        application/rdf+xml
        application/json
        application/ld+json
        application/manifest+json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.geo+json
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/bmp
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/javascript
        text/xml
        text/cache-manifest
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/vcard
        text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
        text/vtt
        text/x-component
        text/x-cross-domain-policy;
        # text/html is always compressed by gzip module


    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    upstream papp {
        server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-papp.sock; #for PHP-FPM running on UNIX socket
    }

    #fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYAPP:100m inactive=60m;
    #fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Here is the vhost:

```
server {
    # set the user that runs nginx & php
    set $phpfcgi papp;

    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    server_name compte.papp.com;
    root /var/www/papp.com/prod/web;

    #ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/papp.com/2018-12-03/compte.pretinstant.com.combined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/papp.com/2018-12-03/compte.papp.com.key;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/papp.com.compte.error.log notice;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/papp.com.compte.access.log;
    #rewrite_log on;


    client_body_buffer_size     100m;
    client_max_body_size        100m;

    # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
    rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
        index app.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server from upstream phpfcgi
    #location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config|js/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/api)\.php(/|$) {

       # Set fastcgi buffer size
        #fastcgi_buffers 32 32k;
        #fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

        fastcgi_pass $phpfcgi;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

}
```

Here is php.conf:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's install
; prefix (/usr). This prefix can be dynamically changed by using the
; '-p' argument from the command line.

; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
; Relative path can also be used. They will be prefixed by:
;  - the global prefix if it's been set (-p argument)
;  - /usr otherwise
;include=/etc/php5/fpm/*.conf

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
; Pid file
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: none
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid

; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; in a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log
error_log = /var/log/php/php5-fpm.log

; syslog_facility is used to specify what type of program is logging the
; message. This lets syslogd specify that messages from different facilities
; will be handled differently.
; See syslog(3) for possible values (ex daemon equiv LOG_DAEMON)
; Default Value: daemon
;syslog.facility = daemon

; syslog_ident is prepended to every message. If you have multiple FPM
; instances running on the same server, you can change the default value
; which must suit common needs.
; Default Value: php-fpm
;syslog.ident = php-fpm

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
;log_level = notice

; If this number of child processes exit with SIGSEGV or SIGBUS within the time
; interval set by emergency_restart_interval then FPM will restart. A value
; of '0' means 'Off'.
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_threshold = 0

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_interval = 0

; Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master.
; Available units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;process_control_timeout = 0

; The maximum number of processes FPM will fork. This has been design to control
; the global number of processes when using dynamic PM within a lot of pools.
; Use it with caution.
; Note: A value of 0 indicates no limit
; Default Value: 0
; process.max = 128

; Specify the nice(2) priority to apply to the master process (only if set)
; The value can vary from -19 (highest priority) to 20 (lower priority)
; Note: - It will only work if the FPM master process is launched as root
;       - The pool process will inherit the master process priority
;         unless it specified otherwise
; Default Value: no set
; process.priority = -19

; Send FPM to background. Set to 'no' to keep FPM in foreground for debugging.
; Default Value: yes
;daemonize = yes

; Set open file descriptor rlimit for the master process.
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit for the master process.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_core = 0

; Specify the event mechanism FPM will use. The following is available:
; - select     (any POSIX os)
; - poll       (any POSIX os)
; - epoll      (linux >= 2.5.44)
; - kqueue     (FreeBSD >= 4.1, OpenBSD >= 2.9, NetBSD >= 2.0)
; - /dev/poll  (Solaris >= 7)
; - port       (Solaris >= 10)
; Default Value: not set (auto detection)
;events.mechanism = epoll

; When FPM is build with systemd integration, specify the interval,
; in second, between health report notification to systemd.
; Set to 0 to disable.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default value: 10
;systemd_interval = 10

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Multiple pools of child processes may be started with different listening
; ports and different management options.  The name of the pool will be
; used in logs and stats. There is no limitation on the number of pools which
; FPM can handle. Your system will tell you anyway :)

; To configure the pools it is recommended to have one .conf file per
; pool in the following directory:
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

Here is the pool.d/papp.conf, in a gist since I busted caracter limit:

https://gist.github.com/stefgosselin/5a668d2af5adc5b273e2f07def1d07d7